# Asp.Net MVC. Hot to transmit data from view to controller without dataloss

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to asp.net and currently trying to make a form to add some data to my database.
When I'm trying to send data from the view to my [HttpPost] method in the controller sadly all the information from my POST is lost for some reason. To give you a rough idea how my data structure looks like: I'm having a course which cointans a list of question Objects which has a list of answer Objects.
So that given, this is how i build up my code.
Calling the view:

```
ViewBag.QuestionId = -1;
return View("QuestionForms", _context.Courses.Include(c => c.Questions.Select(q => q.PossibleAnswers)).Single(c => c.Id == course.Id));
```

Here's the View:

```
@using System
@using CourseTec.Models
@model CourseTec.Models.Course
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "QuestionForms";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveQuestions", "Course"))
{
var index = ViewBag.QuestionId;

if (Model.Questions != null && index != -1)
{

}
else
{
    Model.Questions.Add(new Question());
    index = Model.Questions.Last().Id;
}
var concreteQuestion = Model.Questions.Find(x => x.Id == index);
var questionIndex = Model.Questions.FindIndex(x => x == concreteQuestion);
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Questions[questionIndex].question)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.Questions[questionIndex].question, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Questions[questionIndex].PossibleAnswers[k].AnswerString)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.Questions[questionIndex].PossibleAnswers[k].AnswerString, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Questions[questionIndex].PossibleAnswers[k].CorrectAnswer)
    </div>
}

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id);
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

And this one is the ActionResult called after submitting

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveQuestions(Course course)
{
    if (course.Id == 0)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        var courseInDb = _context.Courses.Include(i => i.Questions.Select(s => s.PossibleAnswers)).Single(c => c.Id == course.Id);
        courseInDb.Questions.Add(course.Questions[0]);
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();
    return View("CourseForms",(_context.Courses.Include(i => i.Questions.Select(s => s.PossibleAnswers)).Single(c => c.Id == course.Id)));
}
```

Interesting is that the first item can be addet without dataloss or any other problems but trying to add any more will result in this problem.

So I would be happy if someone could tell me why the data from the POST isn't recognized or somewhat ignored by the ActionResult method.

I want to note, that the POST seems to be correct, as shown by the networks tab from my browser:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of get method.

Comment: Please post actual code, not screenshots.

Comment: @3Dave  I did, sorry for that.

Comment: Give us your `Course` class structure, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Model.Questions[questionIndex]`, start index should from `0` instead of `1`

You should customer name to correct, looks like this

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.Questions[questionIndex].PossibleAnswers[k].AnswerString, new { @class = "form-control", Name = "Questions["+ k + "].PossibleAnswers["+ k + "].AnswerString" })
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the index, since i already have 1 entry in my database, so the 1 index is for the 2nd entry.
Can you explain why it requires a name to fix it? Shouldn't it by default work without it and drop it into the current model, which is then returned to the controller as parameter of the ActionResult? Just asking for better understanding.

Comment: It also works with
`@Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.Questions[0].PossibleAnswers[k].AnswerString, new { @class = "form-control"}`
Problem is, that I will allways load the [0] element into the forms instead of the question I want to edit. So is there a dynamic way to get the [x]element loaded to the form while returning a working model as parameter to the ActionResult? (since it obviously needs [0])